# Composite C1 Installation Fails (web platform installer)

Tags: c1-cms

A couple of years ago I setup a couple of Composite C1 (4) sites.

I just tried to create a new site using the web platform installer - but at the end of the installation I always get this error:

Composite C1 .NET CMS
This product did not install successfully: This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.

(I can't find mention of this in Google).

How can I get this working - pretty bad that it fails right out of WPI like this. Thanks.

[image]

Now after selecting IIS Express - it gets further then comes up with "An unfortunate error has occurred"

[image]

Comment: I managed to fix it by selecting 'IIS Express' rather than IIS during installation. Perhaps it is a permission issue creating a folder or something?! I would still like to install under full IIS if possible.

Comment: spoke too soon - I now get "An unfortunate error has occurred" during the IIS Express web interface setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I granted full write & full control access to the wwwroot folder to the IIS_IUSRS user.

This fixed the IIS install.